# Why do my PDF fonts look different in Firefox and Chromium?

Tags: firefox, pdf, fonts

What could be causing this error? I refer to this as an error because I can barely read the letters when they're squished together in Firefox.

In Firefox 65.0, fonts in a PDF look like this:

[image: ![Firefox, non-italicized fonts]

In Chromium 71.0.3578.80, they look like this:

[image: Chromium, non-italicized fonts]

I'm running both browsers on Debian 9.7, and I have disabled all extensions in both browsers.

Comment: The italics appear to be different versions of the font, it isn't just a matter of spacing.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I fixed the image. I had uploaded the Chromium image twice. Sorry!

Comment: These appear to be different fonts.  They're similar, so there may be font substitution going on.

Comment: @fixer1234 Do you know how to control Firefox's font substitutions? I view a lot of PDFs in Firefox and its fonts are quite difficult on my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFs can be created with fonts embedded, which results in a larger file size, but more consistent display across all viewers, or with fonts not embedded, which creates a smaller file, but there can be consistency issues as the available fonts may vary.

Because most PDFs are generated for web sharing, and absolutely consistent layout is not super important, in most cases the fonts are not embedded.

How the fonts are referenced can also allow for some variance even on the same system. While I don't know for certain, I'd imagine that PDF supports font families in much the same way HTML rendering works, as in, you can tell the PDF you'd like a generic italic serif font for this block of text, and based on a given set of preferences defined in the viewer it will select its own preference.

If you were to view a PDF created with the fonts fully embedded, display should be more consistent across a wider range of viewers.